# Can't change object into array php

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I am using google spreadsheet API and I try to convert Object into array in php.

Please tell me how can I access like object or array key, value pair. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
Array
(
[Google\Spreadsheet\Worksheetxml] => Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [0] => https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/private/full/od6
            )

        [updated] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2017-03-01T14:18:45.232Z
            )

        [category] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006
                        [term] => http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#worksheet
                    )

            )

        [title] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sheet1
            )

        [content] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sheet1
            )

        [link] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#listfeed
                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                [href] => https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/od6/private/full
                            )

                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cellsfeed
                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                [href] => https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/od6/private/full
                            )

                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/visualization/2008#visualizationApi
                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                [href] => https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/gviz/tq?gid=0
                            )

                    )

                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#exportcsv
                                [type] => text/csv
                                [href] => https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/export?gid=0&format=csv
                            )

                    )

                [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [rel] => self
                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                [href] => https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/private/full/od6
                            )

                    )

                [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [rel] => edit
                                [type] => application/atom+xml
                                [href] => https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/private/full/od6/-u3c64m
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[Google\Spreadsheet\WorksheetpostUrl] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1l5g5HbOuaDVCXb1Z3mMk7UesdJ5OOsUtGEekqDXRd-s/private/full
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: what have your tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this.

```
foreach($yourArray as $key=>$value){
   $Updatedate  =  $value['updated'][0];
   $UpdateId  =  $value['id'][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the object into an array by using the array typecast  like so:

```
$array = (array) $obj;
```

Comment: Can you please post the object you are trying to convert?

Comment: You have posted an array ^ above. If you want to access say the id element you can do this like so: $id = $array['Google\Spreadsheet\Worksheetxml']['id'][0];

Comment: How can I get title value?

Comment: $title = $array['Google\Spreadsheet\Worksheetxml']['title'][0];

Comment: I am getting blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PHP Google Spreadsheet Client library](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client).

You'll need to use the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) as well to authenticate via OAuth2. Developer documentation is linked on the github page.

Comment: Yes i have authenticated it as you said.

Comment: what do you don't understand from here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#making-requests ?